# Simplest way for end users to run Python script on network drive without installation?

Tags: python, batch-file, deployment

I want to start using Python at work, and I have a script that I need all the end users to run on a central network drive.

However, they don't have admin rights to install Python and I am not going to call desktop support and go through that mess. I'm thinking of putting my WinPython installation on the network, pointing to the py.exe in a BAT file, and instruct users to run the BAT file.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using WinPython and that suited my needs nicely. It's a convenient little package.

http://winpython.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using py2exe or Pyinstaller? Pyinstaller converts python scripts to standalone executables that can be run on windows, linux, and Mac OS.

Here's the link to their wiki page on github: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki

Comment: I tried py2exe and didn't have much luck with it. I don't think it likes that I'm using 3.4. I'll check out Pyinstaller next...

Comment: Yeah, i'm not sure if py2exe is supported that much anymore. PyInstaller has worked pretty well for me. I'm using 2.7, but 3.4 should be supported.